# what is magento 2 equivalent of version setup files

Tags: magento2

In magento 1 it was possible to create different version set up scripts i.e

```
install-1.0.0.php
upgrade-1.0.0-1.0.1.php
upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.3.php
```

However in magento 2 there is only one script within a module for

Setup/UpgradeData

I now want to run a second version of the UpgradeData script to add to the previous Upgrade data

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has changed to a more pretty way (I personally think that's ugly), but some months ago it was done this way

Update your module version in your **app/code/XX/XX/etc/module.xml** file (similar as Magento1), in the below example 1.0.1

Update your **app/code/XX/XX/Setup/UpgradeData.php** `upgrade()` method code,

```
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    if(!$context->getVersion()) {
        // code that was executed in your first version
    }

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
        // code executed for 1.0.1 version
    }

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Take a look, for instance, at **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Setup/UpgradeData.php** to get a better idea if above example was not clear